# Is there a pythonic way to check if a prompt or input statement is a float?

Tags: python-3.x, input, floating-point

Hi I think I see a lot of people having knowledge in depth in field of computer science.

My question is in python3, is there a way to check if an input statement
or a string value is a float?

I am expecting something like

```
str.isfloat()
```

Thank you for taking a look for this poor student :)

Comment: I posted the question because I know there is no such thing as str.isfloat()

Comment: Use the common [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html?highlight=eafp) python style and just catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to the `float` constructor and [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

```
>>> float('1')
1.0
>>> float('2.0')
2.0
>>> float('three')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'three'
```